# Different queues in celery

Tags: python, redis, queue, celery, fastapi

I have a project where I'm starting my FastAPI using a file (python main.py):

```
import uvicorn
from configuration import API_HOST, API_PORT

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("endpoints:app", host="localhost", port=8811, reload=True, access_log=False)
```

Inside endpoints.py I have:

```
from celery import Celery
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
import time

# Create object for fastAPI
app = FastAPI(
    title="MYFASTAPI",
    description="MYDESCRIPTION",
    version=1.0,
    contact="ME!",
)

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.conf.broker_url = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://localhost:6379")
celery.conf.result_backend = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://localhost:6379")
celery.conf.task_track_started = True
celery.conf.task_serializer = pickle
celery.conf.result_serializer = pickle
celery.conf.accept_content = ["pickle"]

# By defaul celery can handle as many threads as CPU cores have the instance. 
celery.conf.worker_concurrency = os.cpu_count()

# Start the celery worker. I start it in a separate thread, so fastapi can run in parallel
worker = celery.Worker()

def start_worker():
    worker.start()

ce = threading.Thread(target=start_worker)
ce.start()

@app.post("/taskA")
def taskA():
    task = ask_taskA.delay()
    return {"task_id": task.id}

@celery.task(name="ask_taskA", bind=True)
def ask_taskA(self):
    time.sleep(100)

@app.post("/get_results")
def get_results(task_id):
    task_result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)
    return {'task_status': task_result.status}
```

Given this code, how can I have two different queues, assign a specific number of workers per earch queue and assign a specific task to one of these queues?

I read that people use to execute celery as:

```
celery -A proj worker
```

but there was a structure in the project that limited me because of some importings, and at the end I finished by starting the celery worker in a different thread (which works perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official celery documentation [https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing[1]](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing%5B1%5D) you can follow this to specify different queues.

```
from kombu import Queue

app.conf.task_default_queue = 'default'
app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('default',    routing_key='task.#'),
    Queue('feed_tasks', routing_key='feed.#'),
)
app.conf.task_default_exchange = 'tasks'
app.conf.task_default_exchange_type = 'topic'
app.conf.task_default_routing_key = 'task.default'
```